# Nassi–Shneiderman diagram with plain TeX

Tags: packages, plain-tex

First I was trying to quickly put together a file/package that provides macros for building Nassi-Shneidermann diagrams, but after a while it gave me a head ache – literally.

So I decided to seek out a package on the internet, especially when I figured out that they are also called this, with no luck. I know of an existing package called `stuki.sty`, but that is for LaTeX, and I couldn't find the `stuki.tex` file that it was based on, as it mentioned by the author. Neither of these available as a package for download.

Is there any kind of package that provides similar?

Also if there is, is there a way to make the conditions one line with the true/false line, the separating lines not going all the way in the middle, [like this](http://lorentey.hu/images/stuki/stuki.gif), and [not like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aTwo-Way_Branch.jpg)?

Comment: The first image is from [this site](http://lorentey.hu/project/stuki.html.en).

Just as an interesting fact: At the authors country, structograms is called in short, written as stuki (pronounced with an sh, uh, ee sounds) because it is difficult for them to pronounce the tr letters _only_ in this word, especially when they hear, and/or say the shortened name.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nassi%E2%80%93Shneiderman_diagram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `\input pstricks.tex` it is plain TeX compatible. Some flowcharts can be seen [here](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-node/psmatrix/psmatrix#flowchart):
not really as a tabular like nassi-shneiderman, but it should be easy to realize.
Here is a start for your example:

```
\input pstricks
\input pst-node

\pspicture(0,1)(10,-7)
\rput(5,0){\rnode{A}{\psframebox[framearc=0.3]{Your reall long text}}}
\rput(5,-1){\rnode{B}{\psframe(-5,0)(5,-1)\rput(0,-0.5){And the next one}}}
\ncline[arrowscale=2,arrows=->,angleA=-90,angleB=90]{A}{B}
\psframe(0,-1)(10,-7)      \rput(6,-2.5){foo}
\psline(1,-4)(1,-2)(10,-2) \rput(6,-3.5){bar}
\psline(1,-3)(10,-3)       \rput(6,-4.5){foo bar}
\psline(0,-4)(10,-4)
\psline(0,-5)(10,-5)
\endpspicture
\bye
```

Comment: Yes, I found that one, but I'm specifically interested in NSD. Thanks anyway. (I wait for some time before I mark it as a solution.)

Comment: @Adam: I put some code into the answer